# Can I render HTML from SQL Database in SSRS 2005?

Tags: html, reporting-services, rendering, reportingservices-2005

I have html in an MS SQL DB. I would like to render the html on a SSRS page, is this possible?

Comment: I have done this by writing a custom control as another user mentioned. Such a PITA!

Comment: rkarajan can you share where / what you wrote this in?  Can you post more info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of capability was deliberately disabled in SQL 2005 Reporting Services because of 'security reasons'.  I believe the advice at the time was to record any html as an image and embed the image in the report. I decided to abandon reporting services all together instead.  Sorry!

If you are using [SQL 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx) you can use some HTML in your reports.  However, there are some limitations to the markups that can be used:

> The following is a complete list of
>   tags that will render as HTML when
>   defined as placeholder text:
>
> ```
> * Hyperlinks: <A href>
> * Fonts: <FONT>
> * Header, style and block elements: <H{n}>, <DIV>, <SPAN>,<P>,
>           <DIV>, <LI>, <HN>
> * Text format: <B>, <I>, <U>, <S>
> * List handling: <OL>, <UL>, <LI>
> ```
>
> Any other HTML markup tags will be
>   ignored during report processing

Comment: Hi, I am rendering a hyperlink, like "<a href="myurl" target="_blank",  but when the report is rendered, it is ignoring the target="_blank", do you know why is that happening?

Comment: No idea, sorry!  I haven't used SSRS for years now.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe so. The output that is created from an SSRS report is not an HTML document and I've never been able to get html output to render correctly in the report.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any easy way of doing it, you may have to write your own custom control  to do this.